# Sequence of Hilbert Schmidt operators

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Consider the Banach space $\mathcal K=S_2(H)$ of Hilbert Schmidt operators on a Hilbert space $H$. I am looking for an example of two pairs of sequences $\{T^{(i)}\},\{\tilde T^{(j)}\}$ and $\{S^{(i)}\},\{\tilde S^{(j)}\}$ in the unit ball of $\mathcal K$ and an anti-linear operator $\phi:\mathcal K\to \mathcal K$ such that the both iterated limits exists but $$\lim_i\lim_j\sum_{r,s}T^{(i)}_{rs}\tilde T^{(j)}_{rs}\overline{\phi(S^{(i)}\star \tilde S^{(j)})_{rs}}\neq \lim_j\lim_i\sum_{r,s}T^{(i)}_{rs}\tilde T^{(j)}_{rs}\overline{\phi(S^{(i)}\star \tilde S^{(j)})_{rs}}$$

Where $T_{rs}$ denote the $r\times s$ entry in the matrix of $T$ and "$\star$" denotes the Schur product of operators(entrywise product of matrices).

(Or otherwise, prove that these limits are always equal irrespective of the choice of sequences in unit ball and $\phi$).

Comment: I guess $H$ comes with a fixed orthonormal basis, which allows us to think of elements of $\mathcal K$ as matrices.  I think the "anti-linear operator" a bit unnatural and unmotivated.  Given $\phi$ cannot I define $\psi:\mathcal K\rightarrow\mathcal K$ by $\psi(T)_{rs} = \overline{\phi(T)_{rs}}$.  Then $\psi$ is bounded exactly when $\phi$ is bounded (I guess $\phi$ is bounded?) and is linear.  Why couldn't we work with $\psi$ to start with?

Comment: Actually, I am dealing with the bilinear forms of type $m:\mathcal K\times\mathcal K\to \mathbb C$ such that $m(S,T)=\left<T,\phi(S)\right>=\sum_{r,s}T_{rs}\overline{\phi(S)_{rs}}$, hence I need it to be anti-linear bounded map.

Comment: But I guess what you said is true. A linear and bounded operator would suffice for a counterexample.

Comment: Is this the paper you refer to when you say (in the bounty) 'Need this for my paper"? https://arxiv.org/abs/2001.00830

Comment: Yes it is @yemon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The limits are always the same.

As $\mathcal K = S_2(H)$ is a Hilbert space, and as only the Schur product is involved anywhere, we can infact identify $\mathcal K$ with $\ell^2 = \ell^2(\mathbb N)$ and consider the pointwise product of vectors in $\ell^2$.

Let $x=(x_r)\in\ell^2$ and let $(y^{(i)})$ be a bounded sequence in $\ell^2$.  Thus, for each $r$ the scalar sequence $(y^{(i)}_r)$ is bounded, so by moving to subsequences and using a diagonal argument, we may suppose that $y^{(i)}_r\rightarrow y_r$, say, as $i\rightarrow\infty$.  Set $y=(y_r)$ and observe that for any $R$,
$$ \sum_{r=1}^R |y_r|^2 = \sum_{r=1}^R \lim_i |y^{(i)}_r|^2
= \lim_i \sum_{r=1}^R |y^{(i)}_r|^2
\leq \lim_i \|y^{(i)}\|_2^2 < \infty. $$
As $R$ was arbitrary, we conclude that $y\in\ell^2$.
Then, for $R>0$,
\begin{align*} \lim_i \|xy^{(i)} - xy\|_2^2
&= \lim_i \sum_r |x_r y^{(i)}_r - x_r y_r|^2 \\\\
&= \sum_{r=1}^R \lim_i |x_r y^{(i)}_r - x_r y_r|^2
+ \lim_i \sum_{r>R} |x_r y^{(i)}_r - x_r y_r|^2 \\\\
&= \lim_i \sum_{r>R} |x_r y^{(i)}_r - x_r y_r|^2 \\\\
&\leq \lim_i \Big(\sum_{r>R} |y^{(i)}_r - y_r|^2\Big) \Big( \sup_{r>R} |x_r| \Big).
\end{align*}
We can make this arbitrarily small by choosing $R$ large.  We conclude that $xy^{(i)} \rightarrow xy$ in norm.

Given bounded sequences $(x^{(i)}), (y^{(i)})$ in $\ell^2$, let $x,y$ be the pointwise limits, as in the previous paragraph.  Let $z\in\ell^2$, and consider
\begin{align*} \lim_i \sum_r x^{(i)}_r z_r y^{(i)}_r. \end{align*}
As $x^{(i)} y^{(i)}$ is in $\ell^1$ and $(z_r)$ is bounded, this sum make sense, and we can copy the argument to show that
\begin{align*} \lim_i \sum_r x^{(i)}_r z_r y^{(i)}_r
= \sum_r x_r z_r y_r
. \end{align*}

Thus, given bounded sequences $(x^{(i)}), (y^{(i)}), (a^{(i)}), (b^{(i)})$ in $ell^2$, let $x,y,a,b$ be the pointwise limits, as in the previous paragraph.  Given a bounded linear map $\phi$ on $\ell^2$, we see that as $a^{(i)} b^{(j)} \rightarrow a b^{(j)}$ in norm, as $i\rightarrow\infty$, also $\phi(a^{(i)} b^{(j)}) \rightarrow \phi(a b^{(j)})$ in norm.  Hence, by the same argument,
\begin{align*}
\lim_j \lim_i \sum_r x^{(i)}_r y^{(j)}_r \phi(a^{(i)} b^{(j)})_r
= \lim_j \sum_r x_r y^{(j)}_r \phi(a b^{(j)})_r
= \sum_r x_r y_r \phi(a b)_r.
\end{align*}
By symmetry, we get the same answer with the limits taken in the other order.